# else if statements in C++

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

i want to make a program which greets people differently according to their name, please dont get offended by the print statements it is just a prank for my friends. I am a beginner plz help. here's my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;
    cout<<"Please enter your name."<<endl;
    getline(cin, a);

    cin>>a>>endl;

   
        if(a=="daksh" || a=="Daksh"){
    cout<<"Chlaja bsdk 凸 ( ͡❛ 皿 ͡❛)凸"<<endl;
}
else if(a=="Harsh" || a=="harsh"){
    cout<<"Bsdk MC behn K lode , machhar ki jhaat maki chut teri tatto ke saudagar (ง ͡❛ 皿 ͡❛)ง"<<endl;
}
else if(a=="Sparsh" || a=="sparsh"){
    cout<<"Jahapana tussi geat ho , tofu kubul kro. /( ͡❛ ͜ʖ ͡❛)/"<<endl;
}
else {
    cout<<"Hello ,dear"<<a<<endl;
            }
return 0;
}
```

**these are the errors , i have not posted all the errors because it is exceeding the word limit.**

```
    greetings.cpp: In function 'int main()':
    greetings.cpp:12:11: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream<char>' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>')
         cin>>a>>endl;
         ~~~~~~^~~~~~
    In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:40:0,
                     from greetings.cpp:1:
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:120:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(__istream_type& (*__pf)(__istream_type&))
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:120:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type&) {aka std::basic_istream<char>& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>&)}'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:124:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]
           operator>>(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:124:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)}'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:131:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(ios_base& (*__pf)(ios_base&))
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:131:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:168:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(bool&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(bool& __n)
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:168:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'bool&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:172:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
           operator>>(short& __n);
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:172:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'short int&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:175:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short 
    unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(unsigned short& __n)
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:175:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'short unsigned int&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:179:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
           operator>>(int& __n);
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:179:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'int&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:182:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(unsigned int& __n)
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:182:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'unsigned int&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:186:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(long& __n)
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:186:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'long int&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:190:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(unsigned long& __n)
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:190:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'long unsigned int&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:195:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(long long& __n)
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:195:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'long long int&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:199:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(unsigned long long& __n)
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:199:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'long long unsigned int&'        
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:214:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(float&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(float& __f)
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:214:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'float&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:218:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(double&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(double& __f)
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:218:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'double&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:222:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long double&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(long double& __f)
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:222:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'long double&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:235:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(void*&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
           operator>>(void*& __p)
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:235:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'void*&'
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:259:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]
           operator>>(__streambuf_type* __sb);
           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:259:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char>*}'
    In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\string:53:0,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:42,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                     from greetings.cpp:1:
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc:1437:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
         operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in,
         ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc:1437:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
greetings.cpp:12:13: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Alloc'
     cin>>a>>endl;
             ^~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:40:0,
                 from greetings.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:799:5: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT2, _Traits2>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT2, _Traits2>&, _CharT2*) [with _CharT2 = char; _Traits2 = std::char_traits<char>; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
     operator>>(basic_istream<char>& __in, char* __s);
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:799:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'char*'
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:934:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:40,
                 from greetings.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc:923:5: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT& __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc:923:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'char&'
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:40:0,
                 from greetings.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:756:5: note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char& __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:756:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
greetings.cpp:12:13: note:   cannot convert 'std::endl' (type '<unresolved overloaded function type>') to type 'unsigned char&'
     cin>>a>>endl;
             ^~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:40:0,
                 from greetings.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:761:5: note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char& __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:761:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
greetings.cpp:12:13: note:   cannot convert 'std::endl' (type '<unresolved overloaded function type>') to type 'signed char&'
     cin>>a>>endl;
             ^~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:40:0,
                 from greetings.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:803:5: note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:803:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
greetings.cpp:12:13: note:   cannot convert 'std::endl' (type '<unresolved overloaded function type>') to type 'unsigned char*'
     cin>>a>>endl;
             ^~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:40:0,
                 from greetings.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:808:5: note: candidate: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:808:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
greetings.cpp:12:13: note:   cannot convert 'std::endl' (type '<unresolved overloaded function type>') to type 'signed char*'
     cin>>a>>endl;
             ^~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:40:0,
                 from greetings.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:924:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Tp> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, _Tp&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __is, _Tp& __x)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:924:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
greetings.cpp:12:13: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Tp'
     cin>>a>>endl;
             ^~~~
```

Comment: your if statements are not end, listen the compiler carefully.

Comment: In your own words, what are the `{` and `}`s for in this program? How did you decide to put them where you did? Now, try looking at a tutorial that talks about how to use `if` and `else if` and `else`. Where did they put the `{` and `}`s? Do you understand why?

Comment: Along with the incorrect placement of your closing braces `}` you also need to `#include <string>`

Comment: i did all the changes u guys suggested but now it is showing these errors

Comment: @CloseVoters, the if-else problem here is not a typo. It's a consistent misunderstanding, so this is not a reason to close the question.

Comment: First you do `getline(cin, a);`, and then `cin>>a>>endl;`. Why do you read `a` twice, and what do you think *reading* into `endl` would mean? Did you intend to write `cout<<a<<endl;` in order to check what the input was?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to make a new question - it makes all answers irrelevant. Post a new question, and make it a [mcve]. (You can reproduce the problem in the current state with `int main() { string a; cin >> a >> endl;}`)

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to close the if brackets like that you need to close it after every condition

```
if(a>b)
{
print(a);
}
else if(b>c)
{
print(b);
}
```

....

Answer (score 0):

The code was full of format and writing errors.The main problem is that you have to close the bracets after each if/else not at the end.You have the good code down:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;
    cout<<"Please enter your name."<<endl;
    getline(cin, a);

    cin>>a;


    if(a=="daksh" || a=="Daksh"){
        cout<<"Chlaja bsdk 凸 ( ͡❛ 皿 ͡❛)凸"<<endl;
    }else if(a=="Harsh" || a=="harsh"){
        cout<<"Bsdk MC behn K lode , machhar ki jhaat maki chut teri tatto ke saudagar (ง ͡❛ 皿 ͡❛)ง"<<endl;
    }else if(a=="Sparsh" || a=="sparsh"){
        cout<<"Jahapana tussi geat ho , tofu kubul kro. /( ͡❛ ͜ʖ ͡❛)/"<<endl;
    }else {
        cout<<"Hello ,dear"<<a<<endl;
    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have done the changes and edited the ques now it is now also showing errors plz consider it.

Comment: You can't and you don't need to use ">>endl" for "cin"

Comment: @SparshKarna Please don't fix code in your question after getting an answer. It will invalidate all the answers that were given until now. Instead accept the answer you find the most helpful and ask a new question for a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Properly reformatted, your current version of the `if` will look like this:

```
    if(a=="daksh" || a=="Daksh")
    {
        cout<<"Chlaja bsdk 凸 ( ͡❛ 皿 ͡❛)凸"<<endl;
        else if(a=="Harsh" || a=="harsh") // ******** dangling else
        {
            cout<<"Bsdk MC behn K lode , machhar ki jhaat maki chut teri tatto ke saudagar (ง ͡❛ 皿 ͡❛)ง"<<endl;
            else if(a=="Sparsh" || a=="sparsh") // ******** dangling else
            {
                cout<<"Jahapana tussi geat ho , tofu kubul kro. /( ͡❛ ͜ʖ ͡❛)/"<<endl;
                else // ******** dangling else
                {
                    cout<<"Hello ,dear"<<a<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note the "dangling else" marks I've added. You instead want to put `else` at the same level as corresponding `if`, not inside the statement guarded by the `if`. I.e.

```
if(condition)
{
    statement_if_true;
}
else
{
    statement_if_false;
}
```

instead of

```
// WRONG!
if(condition)
{
    statement_if_true;
    else // dangling else
    {
        statement_if_false;
    }
}
```

---

Besides the `if` problem, you also attempt to "write" into the `std::endl`, *output* manipulator. This doesn't make sense, which is what the first error message tells you.

Answer (score 0):

curly braces are wrongly typed

you can match your code with mine here.

happy coding.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;
    cout<<"Please enter your name."<<endl;

    cin >> a;

   
    if(a=="daksh" || a=="Daksh"){
        
        cout<<"Chlaja bsdk 凸 ( ͡❛ 皿 ͡❛)凸"<<endl;

    }
    else if(a=="Harsh" || a=="harsh"){
        cout<<"Bsdk MC behn K lode , machhar ki jhaat maki chut teri tatto ke saudagar (ง ͡❛ 皿 ͡❛)ง"<<endl;
    }
    else if(a=="Sparsh" || a=="sparsh"){
        
        cout<<"Jahapana tussi geat ho , tofu kubul kro. /( ͡❛ ͜ʖ ͡❛)/"<<endl;
    }
    else {cout<<"Hello ,dear"<<a<<endl;}
 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are sure that he needs the string header file? For me his code worked even without it. You might want to try it out.

Comment: for running this code string header file not required. thanks for pointing it out.